# Как найти подстроку в строках listbox'a?

Tags: c++, winapi

```
case CBN_SELCHANGE:
        {



            int idx_row;
            char strText[255] = { 0 };
            idx_row = SendMessage(hComboBox, CB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0);
            SendMessage(hComboBox, CB_GETLBTEXT, idx_row, (LPARAM)strText);//парсим строку из комбобокса типа ".exe"

            int index = SendMessage(hwndList1, LB_FINDSTRING, (WPARAM)(-1), (LPARAM)(strText));//индекс строки с данным расширением

            do
            {

                SendMessage(hwndList1, LB_SETSEL, TRUE, (LPARAM)index);//выделяем строки листбокса

            } while (SendMessage(hwndList1, LB_SETSEL, TRUE, (LPARAM)index) != LB_ERR);



            break;
        }
```

в strText кладется расширение типа ".exe", а в листбоксе находится список имен файлов. Не получается выделить все файлы с выбранным расширением...

Comment: в комбобоксе строки типа ".txt", а в листбоксе может быть файл "asd.exe" или "dasdasd.txt".

Comment: Что значит "не получается"? Зачем тут `do ...  while`?

Comment: @VTT, ну мне нужно выделить все строки, где, например, найдется ".exe" подстрока, поэтоу поставил do while.

Comment: Так в цикле `SendMessage` вызывается с одними и теми же параметрами.

Comment: @VTT, ой, index в цикле был, поэтому индекс выделяемого элемента изменялся.